# Android Custom SeekBar From Image

Tags: android, drawable, seekbar, xml-drawable

I'm trying to achieve an effect of android seekbar where the background image of the seekbar revealed with the progress, like :

[image]

and the whole overlay image of the seekbar is one image like :

[image]

didn't find a way to do it.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: did you try anything yet?

Comment: You need a `Paint` with custom `Shader` containing `Bitmap` of image that is opening when progress slider moves. So you will need to override `onDraw()` method of your custom view, to do the following: 1) draw black backgroud rectangle; 2) draw rectangle from left edge to position of slider using mentioned custom Paint; 3) draw the slider.